# Static map and SLAM mapping

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, static-map, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

What is the difference between static map and map I get from slam or map I draw myself(in .pgm file)?

Because I am using amcl to do known mapping currently and these .pgm image file together with .yaml is working fine to be placed into map_server. And if I were to visualize my map in 3d form (instead of shaded region as wall maybe I can make them looks like a block), is static map what I need?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103846/static-map-and-slam-mapping/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A static map gets loaded once during startup (or at least that´s the most common usage) and does not get modified over time. During Simultaneous Localization and Mapping (SLAM), the map changes over time as the robot localizes itself in the environment and updates the map.

A .pgm map is essentially just an image file and it does not matter in which way it was created ([gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping), [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping) or even just drawing it yourself). You can open a map created with gmapping using some image editor, change parts of it, save it and then use it as a static map for AMCL.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-08-30**:
How to manually draw the static map(.pgm file) instead of Laser SLAM.Is it possible to create ROS SLAM map using CAD drawings?